# Why Qt text layout eats letters when dealing with non-breakable spaces?

Tags: qt, qt5, richtext, qtextdocument

Test code (Qt5.5.1):

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTextBrowser textBrowser;
    textBrowser.setHtml("<p style=\"font-size: 50pt\">X АБ&nbsp;Y</p>");

    textBrowser.resize(200, 200);
    textBrowser.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Result:

[image: result]

How can I avoid non-ascii letters (like 'А' in test) followed by text with non-breakable spaces disappearing?

Comment: Could you explain yourself better please?

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Works fine for me (Qt 5.8, Linux).

Comment: In Qt 5.5 code above displays "X Б Y" instead of "X АБ Y" i.e. eats letter 'А' at new line.

Comment: Then maybe Qt 5.5 had a bug?

Comment: Can't reproduce on 5.8 on either Windows 10 or OS X 10.10.

Comment: Thank you all, is was fixed after 5.5 apparently. Unfortunately, I am stuck with 5.5.